# Android : Different Background colors for different CardViews?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-cardview

I have a **SQLite database** which feeds data to the cardviews via an **ArrayList**. Every record in the database consists of a different color code, I want to set the background color of each individual card to its respective color present in the database. Color codes are under the "***color***" column inside the database.

Now here's my code, as you can see my **SQL SELECT Query** should only select ONE PARTICULAR RECORD for each individual card but what is doing here is that it selects **all the records** present in database.

If I use `c.moveToFirst();` it selects the first row of the table and if I use `c.moveToLast();` it selects the last row of the table? If I am clearing mentioning `...where id ="+cardid+";"`, isn't it supposed to select only one particular row?

The problem I am facing here is that it sets a common background color for all cardviews, I need it to be different for every card. What am I doing wrong?

*Code Reference :*

TextView **myid** consists of the unique identifier of every record in the database

```
  PersonViewHolder(View itemView, final Activity theact) {
            super(itemView);
            personName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
            personAge = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_age);
            personPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);
            myid = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.IDTAG);
            ohcolor = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.COLORCODE);

            cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            cv.setUseCompatPadding(true);

            openDatabase();

            final String cardid = myid.getText().toString().trim();
            c = db.rawQuery("SELECT color FROM persons WHERE id ="+cardid+";", null);

            c.moveToFirst();
            colorbro = c.getString(0);
            i = Integer.parseInt(colorbro);
            cv.setCardBackgroundColor(i);


            cv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                     // do something
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are having only one reference to cardView which is getting updated, the moment you assign new object to it.

Replace this line of code

```
cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
```

with this

```
CardView cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
```

This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The docs for `db.rawQuery` say "The SQL string must not be ; terminated", so that is potentially your problem. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Comment: I tried removing the "terminator" but it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to get color from `colors.xml` file is either provide color name or its id to `getColor` method:

```
i = Integer.parseInt(colorbro);

cv.setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, i));
```

I am not sure what you have in your `i` variable. Debug and see if it has the correct value.

Comment: read the crash log to see what it says. also, what is stored in `i`?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself, we can set the background color of the card inside **OnBindViewHolder** method

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, int i) {
        personViewHolder.myid.setText(persons.get(i).id);
        personViewHolder.personName.setText(persons.get(i).name);
        personViewHolder.personAge.setText(persons.get(i).age);
        personViewHolder.personPhoto.setImageResource(persons.get(i).photoId);

        personViewHolder.ohcolor.setText(persons.get(i).color);

         //setting background color here
        personViewHolder.cv.setCardBackgroundColor(Integer.parseInt(persons.get(i).color));
    }
```

Here, **persons** is an ArrayList getting data from the SQLite database. As my database also has a column for color codes, I feed it to the ArrayList and retrieve it inside **OnBindViewHolder** and set the background color for each individual card.